# Issue upgrading Terraform versions

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Terraform noob here, so please bear with.

I've been tasked to update all our TF modules to the latest (or close to). Currently on v0.12 and aiming to get them to 1.2 . For the initial update I ran:

```
terraform 0.13upgrade
```

Fine, no problems and now on v0.13.. Now I need to progressively update them as stated in the TF upgrade guides: https://www.terraform.io/language/upgrade-guides/0-14

Shockingly, there appears to be little guidance on how to do this in its basic. So *I think* I update this using `tfswitch` (which can also be done using `tfenv`) and run:

`tfswitch 0.14.0` >
plan/apply

`tfswitch 0.15.0` >
plan/apply

`tfswitch 1.0.0` >
plan/apply

The statefile is stored remotely, so when I pull this down and grep the version

```
grep terraform_version ec2.tfstate
  "terraform_version": "1.0.0"
```

Now the issue I appear to be having is that I cannot get above v1.0.0>

Same upgrade process as above:

`tfswitch 1.1.0` >
plan/apply

but then when i look at the state after the update it remains the same?!

```
grep terraform_version ec2.tfstate
      "terraform_version": "1.0.0"
```

What am I doing wrong, or should I even be upgrading this differently?

Comment: Are you facing any errors?

Comment: No errors at all.

Comment: I decided to make a small change in the module so that it would plan/apply some newly created resources. After doing so the tf version also upgraded!

 ```grep terraform_version ec2.tfstate
      "terraform_version": "1.2.0"```

Does this mean in order to upgrade there needs to updates to the tf state file(s) ?

Comment: The version stored in a state (especially a local file since that is completely arbitrary) is not so important here as a correct infrastructure end state after upgrading. You can focus more on that and less on that JSON kv pair.

Comment: You might find it helpful to read [the v1.0 Upgrade Guide](https://www.terraform.io/language/upgrade-guides/1-0) to get an overview of what other upgrade steps might be needed in order to reach the v1.x series; once you reach a step that says "Upgrade directly to the latest v1.0 release" you can [upgrade directly to the latest v1.2](https://www.terraform.io/language/upgrade-guides/1-2), which is considered to be in "the Terraform v1.0 series" per its upgrade guide.

Answer (score 0):

This post hasn't been receiving much popularity but as per my previous comment:

> I decided to make a small change in the module so that it would plan/apply some newly created resources. After doing so the tf version also upgraded! grep terraform_version ec2.tfstate       "terraform_version": "1.2.0" Does this mean in order to upgrade there needs to updates to the tf state file(s) ?

.. My initial issue appears to be resolved for now. I'm not sure what caused it or if I'm still doing this right but thanks to those have have commented/assisted.